# webView.loadUrl displays a blank screen

Tags: android, webview

I have to load these [Url](http://files.flipsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=fdk843nc&wmode=window&bgcolor=EEEEEE&t=1381431045%22%20width=%22640%22%20height=%22385%22%20seamless=%22seamless%22%20scrolling=%22no%22%20frameborder=%220%22%20allowtransparency=%22true%22) by using the below code.But finally blank screen displayed as a output.you can check the`url` link between code at the `last line`.

**WebPagerLoader.java:**

```
public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
{

final Activity activity = this;
private String html;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

  webView.loadUrl("<iframe src=\"http://files.flipsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=fdk843nc&wmode=window&bgcolor=EEEEEE&t=1381431045\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" seamless=\"seamless\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"></iframe>";
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.webpageloader"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.webpageloader.WebPageLoader"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

finally I get a `blank screen`.I doesn't know what I did `wrong in webView.loadUrl`.
I doesn't know how to solve these.Anybody can help me with these problem.Thank You.

Comment: Try using `str = http://files.flipsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=fdk843nc&wmode=window&bgcolor=EEEEEE&t=1381431045%22%20width=%22640%22%20height=%22385%22%20seamless=%22seamless%22%20scrolling=%22no%22%20frameborder=%220%22%20allowtransparency=%22true%22`         `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, str, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`

Comment: @Aniruddha your previous comment help me to solve these problem.post your answer like these: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<iframe src=\"http://files.flipsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=fdk843nc&wmode=window&bgcolor=EEEEEE&t=1381431045\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" seamless=\"seamless\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"></iframe>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`. then if you provide some explanation with that answer also its better for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your

```
webView.loadUrl("<iframe src=\"http://files.flipsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=fdk843nc&wmode=window&bgcolor=EEEEEE&t=1381431045\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" seamless=\"seamless\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"></iframe>";
```

to

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<iframe src=\"http://files.flipsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=fdk843nc&wmode=window&bg‌​color=EEEEEE&t=1381431045\" width=\"640\" height=\"385\" seamless=\"seamless\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowtransparency=\"true\"></iframe>", "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

The `loadDataWithBaseURL()` method takes, among other parameters, the “base URL” to use when resolving relative URLs in the HTML. Any relative URL (e.g., ) will be interpreted as being relative to the base URL supplied to loadDataWithBaseURL(). If you find that you have content that refuses to load properly with loadData(), try loadDataWithBaseURL() with a null base URL, as sometimes that works better, for unknown reasons.

Comment: > as sometimes that works better, for unknown reasons.
If you don't specify base url, the entire text becomes your url. And if that text contains `#` character, it the is interpreted as anchor and eveything after the `#` character gets cut off.  Probably similar bug exists for other characters too

Answer (score 1):

i have tried and works fine in `webviewFragment`

```
 public class WebPageLoader extends Activity
 {

   final Activity activity = this;
   private String html;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.loadUrl("http://files.flipsnack.com/iframe/embed.html?hash=fdk843nc&wmode=window&bgcolor=EEEEEE&t=1381431045");

       webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
     });

     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

 }
}
```

- its too much memory consuming file so may its no see proper or blank screen but its work fine but not same as web browser