# How to play YouTube video in webview after getting YouTube status in Android?

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, android-webview

I am playing YouTube videos in webview Android. First I am calling the JavaScript functions for getting the status of the YouTube video. When I get the status one at the only I am visible the webview until that webview is visible gone and loading the webview background.

It works fine, but after getting the YouTube video status I am visible the webview it is visible with black screen and spinner is rotating on that screen. Below is my screen:

[image: My screen]

Below is my simple code:

```
final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
        = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
    myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myBrowser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    });
myBrowser.loadUrl("http://Xxxxxxxxxxx/player_android/youtube?videoid=txqiwrbYGrs&st=10&en=20&height=250&width=500&auto=1&ctrl=0&p2p=1");
```

At that time I click on the webview, the video is played successfully. Without touching the webview, the video is not shown on the screen. How to play the YouTube video in webview?

Comment: check this once---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118112/webview-loadurl-displays-a-blank-screen

Comment: @AmarbirSingh i tried the above link but no use for me and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can play the video in WebView.

```
private String url = "http://"; // your video url here

     WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
     webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
     webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
     webview.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

[How to play a video in a webview with android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989738/how-to-play-a-video-in-a-webview-with-android)

Comment: Thanks for reply,already i am using this and webview playing is not a issue.

Comment: means video is not visible to you??

Comment: yes,after visible my webview video is not visible.showing like above screen.when i touch the webview video is visible. that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,as per my knowleadge without using the webchrome client javascript functions are not called.so already i am using the above code.